# I have to write a findStudentWithMaxGPA() method using a for loop but I am stuck as to what to do.

Tags: for-loop

I have to write a findStudentWithMaxGPA() method  that traverses the
array with a for loop and returns out the name of the student with the max
GPA.
However, I don't know how to use a for loop to do this.

```
public class P4CRoster
    {
    private String name;
    private P4C[] students;
    public P4CRoster( )
        {
          students = new P4C[3];
          students[0] = new P4C("Hieu Tran", 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0);
          students[1] = new P4C("Steven Nguyen", 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5);
          students[2] = new P4C("Saul Sanchez", 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0);
        }//end method
    public double findStudentWithMaxGPA()
        {
           double x = students[0].calcGPA();
           double y = students[1].calcGPA();
           double z = students[2].calcGPA();

           x.compareTo(y);
           x.compareTo(z);
           y.compareTo(z);
        }//end method
    public String toString()
        {
           String output = new String();
           output = "The Student with the max GPA is: " + findStudentWithMaxGPA;
           return output;
        }//end toString
}
```

Comment: Knowing there are exactly 3 elements in the array, can you do it *without* a loop?  I see a few calls to `compareTo`, but you don't do anything with their results.

Comment: Please specify language at least...

Comment: The language is Java